# How do I call a invoke an ajax get request from client side, using Node/Express?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, express

I have a file shuffleRoute.js where I define this:

```
router.get("/shuffle?jokers=false", function (req, res) {
   cards['a','b','c'];
   let shuffledCards =  _.shuffle(cards);

    res.status(200).send(shuffledCards);

});
```

I have an index.js where I define:

```
app.get("/v1/game", require("./routes/shuffleRoute.js"));
```

I have a game.html where onload I need to do an ajax request to get the shuffled cards. How do I do that?

doing this

```
  $.get( "/v1/game", function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    });
```

does not work.

I am getting this error:

```
jquery-2.2.4.min.js:4 GET localhost:8080/v1/game 500 (Internal Server Error) –
```

I was using morgan to log things in the server which was incorrectly done.

However, commenting that out gives me this error.

```
jquery-2.2.4.min.js:4 GET http://localhost:8080/v1/game 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Any error on browser console?

Comment: What does "not work" mean?  "not work" is not an acceptable description of the problem.  You have an obligation to do basic troubleshooting yourself and report what you learned when doing that.  What error or response do you get from your ajax call.  Basic troubleshooting would check errors on your ajax call and tell us what it says.

Comment: jquery-2.2.4.min.js:4 GET http://localhost:8080/v1/game 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: So the ajax call is working, the problem is in the server. Check errors in the server console.

Comment: Add that information to your question.  Clearly there is other stuff going on in your server that you have not shown us since no code you've shown us creates a 500 error.

Comment: Thank you. I've added that part to the question. Now I'm getting a 404 error

Comment: Your server is busted and you're not showing us the relevant code where its broken.  Not much we can do.

Answer (score 1):

May be wrong but i see routes problem here.

When you define routes for express use `app.use`

`var myRoute = require('PathToYourRouteFile');`

`app.use("/v1/game", myRoute);`

In route file. Im asuming you use express router you need to define something like this

`youRuoterName.get('/', function(req, res, next) { })`

This request will be succes when you go to `localhost/v1/game`.

If you want another one just do

`youRuoterName.get('/shuffle', function(req, res, next) { })`

Which will be succes when you go to `/v1/game/shuffle`.

In your example i see only one route `/v1/game/shuffle` which clearly not match `/v1/game` and im not even sure that rest of code works as expected.

So please read docs carefuly http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.route
and all should work.

Hope this helps.